# Missing field on cache.writeQuery in Mutation Component?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm studying GraphQL Mutation components. I'm doing a mutation that adds a resolution, i.e. a New Year's resolution. Here's the schema:

```
type Resolution {
  _id: String!
  name: String!
  goals: [Goal]
  completed: Boolean
}

type Query {
  resolutions: [Resolution]
}

type Mutation {
  createResolution(name: String!): {
        Resolution
        user: String
    }
}
```

Here are the resolution resolvers:

```
import Resolutions from "./resolutions";
import Goals from "../goals/goals";
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';

export const pubsub = new PubSub();

export default {
    Query: {
        resolutions(obj, args, { userId }) {
            return Resolutions.find({
                userId
            }).fetch();
        }
    },

    Resolution: {
        goals: resolution =>
            Goals.find({
                resolutionId: resolution._id
            }).fetch(),

        completed: resolution => {
            const goals = Goals.find({
                resolutionId: resolution._id
            }).fetch();
            if (goals.length === 0) return false;
            const completedGoals = goals.filter(goal => goal.completed);
            return goals.length === completedGoals.length;
        }
    },

    Mutation: {
        createResolution(obj, { name }, { userId }) {
            if (userId) {
                const resolutionId = Resolutions.insert({
                    name,
                    userId
                });
                return Resolutions.findOne(resolutionId);
            }
            throw new Error("Unauthortized");
        }
    },
};
```

Here's the user resolver:

```
export default {
  Query: {
    user(obj, args, { user }) {
      return user || {};
    }
  },
  User: {
    email: user => user.emails[0].address
  }
};
```

Here's the mutation component:

```
const ResolutionForm = () => {
    let input;
    let state = {
        error: null
    };

    return (
        <Mutation
            mutation={CREATE_RESOLUTION}
            update={(cache, {data: {createResolution}}) => {
                const {resolutions} = cache.readQuery({query: GET_RESOLUTIONS});
                cache.writeQuery({
                    query: GET_RESOLUTIONS,
                    data: {resolutions: resolutions.concat([createResolution])}
                });
            }}
        >
            {(createResolution, {data}) => (
                <div>
                    <form
                        onSubmit={e => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            createResolution({
                                variables: {
                                    name: input.value
                                },
                            });
                            input.value = "";
                        }}
                    >
                        <input
                            ref={node => {
                                input = node;
                            }}
                        />
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )}
        </Mutation>
    );
};
```

Here's the query that loads all the resolutions when the app launches:

```
const GET_RESOLUTIONS = gql`
  query Resolutions {
    resolutions {
      _id
      name
      completed
      goals {
        _id
        name
        completed
      }
    }
    user {
      _id
    }
  }
`;
```

That works fine, but when I run the mutation:

```
const CREATE_RESOLUTION = gql`
    mutation createResolution($name: String!) {
      createResolution(name: $name) {
        __typename
        _id
        name
        goals {
          _id
          name
          completed
        }
        completed
      }
    }
`;
```

...I get a console log error saying:

```
Missing field user in {
  "resolutions": [
    {
      "_id": "GKTNgbuiDgiZ4wAFZ",
      "name": "testing 123",
      .....
```

How do I get the field `user` into my mutation response?

Comment: Is that possible to cover it by other DataScalarType? 

    `type ResolutionCover {
      resolution: Resolution
      user: String
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GET_RESOLUTIONS query used is originally from a parent component, App.js.  It really contains two separate queries-- one for the resolution and one for the user. The CREATE_RESOLUTION Mutation query and resolver, don't return user data, and I don't yet know how to get them to do that.

But, the Mutation component doesn't need the user data. It only gets upset during the call to `cache.writeQuery` because GET_RESOLUTIONS is asking for `user`, and the Mutation resolver isn't returning `user`.

So the fix seems to be to have a special GET_RESOLUTIONS_FOR_MUTATION_COMPONENT query that doesn't ask for `user` in the first place:

```
const GET_RESOLUTIONS_FOR_MUTATION_COMPONENT = gql`
  query Resolutions {
    resolutions {
      _id
      name
      completed
      goals {
        _id
        name
        completed
      }
    }
  }
`;

[.....]
     const {resolutions} = cache.readQuery({query: GET_RESOLUTIONS_FOR_MUTATION_COMPONENT});
[.....]
```

Using that there is no error message asking for `user`.